# AVAudioPlayer not Play Music again when app run again

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avplayerlayer

I am trying to play save recording files from document directory. The problem is that `AVAudioPlayer` play music only first time after completing recording.
It not play music when i run my app agian.
Xcode gives me that error

```
fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)": file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-703.0.18.8/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 54
```

On this line

```
self.audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePaths[0])
```

I also check file it is exist on directory but it not pick it. Any one have any idea how i can resolve it. [This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxbXpJOTNsSG14SEk) is my demo project.
Thanks

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate{

    var soundRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
    var filePaths : [NSURL]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func playBt(sender: AnyObject) {
        if filePaths.count > 0 {
            //print(soundRecorder.url)
            print(filePaths[0])
            self.audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePaths[0])
            self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            self.audioPlayer.delegate = self
            self.audioPlayer.play()
        }
    }

}*
```

Comment: Can you edit the question so that we can understand the problem. It is difficult to get what is the problem.

Comment: I edit my question.

Comment: `do { self.audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePaths[0]) } catch let error { print(error) }` Actually the framework has some error and it is trying to throw the error. You can check the error and rectify what you are missing.

Comment: I also tried this but this also gives me error.

`fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)": file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-703.0.18.8/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 54`

Comment: Check if there is any file in the location. `fileExistsAtPath:`. If there is a problem, https://www.osstatus.com. This website will let you know what kind of error the errorcode is referring to.

Comment: I was also check this site but it give me audiotoolbox error. I add that framework but still same problem

Comment: file is exist i checked from finder

Comment: What is the fileType of those files. Can iOS read this.

Comment: Just import AVFoundation on header

Comment: Have you checked if the apple supports playing of such audio file. What is the file-type. Sometimes apple might not support this or the file maybe corrupted. Have you tried to play the file on the mac.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124875/discussion-between-zafar007-and-new16).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124893/discussion-between-zafar007-and-new16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code is that you are trying to save the `URL`'s Array to the `UserDefaults`. The container can change anytime, so it is better to save the fileNames in `UserDefaults` and then create the path to document directory using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`.